# Generate a Report via POM after All Tests have been Executed?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Generate a Report via POM after All Tests have been Executed?

1. Lets say I have TestA, TestB, TestC
2. Once all the tests have finished executing is it possible to clean the project (So the latest report is listed in the directory) and then email that report to spcific parties?

thanks for your help

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Is this question about generating some report or emailing it?

Comment: @acikojevic i need to do both, but the report in the project directory needs to be updated before its sent via email, for example TestA, TestB has finished executing, report is updated and then sent via email (All old reports are deleted), thanks

Comment: And how and when are you sending this report currently?

Comment: @acikojevic im sending the report once the Build has finished and all test scripts have finished executing, EmailMethod is in the AfterSuite setup

Answer (score 0):

you can use TestNG, which automatically generates reports of test execution.

Comment: Hi @Kushal the problem I have is when emailing the report it keep sending the report from the last build, unless i clean the project everytime

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how exactly you are running your tests, but you are using maven so you should take advantage of maven lifecycle phases. For example, you could run your tests in `<phase>test</phase>`, and after everything is done you could send mail in later phases (`<phase>package</phase>` or something like that)

Comment: would i add the code listed above within the POM file? for example currently iam: 1. Creating TestNG Test files, 2. Creating TestNG execution files 3. Executing the TestNG file via Maven using Surefire within the POM file 4. Where i need to latest report to be email accross, currently keeps emailing the report from the last maven build / test

Comment: Yes,  it would go in your POM.xml. For sending mail you could use maven-postman-plugin